# Assigning printf output to a variable in awk command

Tags: unix

I want to put leading `0` characters to some input, resulting in a fixed length (length given by a variable). The input can be a number or a string.
I want to catch the output in a variable.

I tried this:

```
awk '{j=$(printf "%04d\n"); echo $j}'
```

but it is throwing this error:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near printf
```

Comment: awk has an sprintf function

Comment: what would be the syntax for assigning to a variable in awk for case like below awk '{j=$(printf "%04d\n"); echo $j}'

Comment: Perhaps change the title of the question into something like "How can I format a string into a fixed length with leading characters"

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
 awk '{j=sprintf("%04d", NR); print j}'
```

to put the record number in the variable j.

Comment: awk '{j=$(sprintf "%04d\n"); echo $j}'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near %04d

Comment: You need an argument for that format string.  What number are you trying to get?  Also, the newline is redundant, since the `print` statement will add one.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to put the record number in the variable.

Comment: need to assign something like j="0000" in awk where number of zeros is not hardcoded. so i am trying to use j=$(sprintf "%04d\n") where value 4 or what ever number will be passing thru a variable

Comment: Sounds like you want `j=sprintf("%04d", 0)`.  Or, if 4 is a variable, something like: `echo foo | awk '{j=sprintf("%0"n"d", 0); print j}'  n=7`

Comment: i am using some thing like this  awk '{k=8-length($1); l=printf("%0"k"i",0);printf "%s %d\n",l$1,$2}' filename   but is throwing error. I need to append with leading zeros and first column data has alpha numeric characters

Comment: sample input file
A100 0000abc 1A20 345
A200 0000cdv 3A45 123
A20 0000 11213 0000
A210 0000 11234 456

first field should be length 8 and need to have leading zeros 

Required output
0000A100 0000abc 1A20 345
0000A200 0000cdv 3A45 123
00000A20 0000 11213 0000
0000A210 0000 11234 456

tried something like this , but not working
awk '{k=8-length($1); l=printf("%0"k"i",0);printf "%s %d\n",l$1,$2}' filename

Comment: So you want to output the first column 8 characters wide with zero padding?  Probably easier to use gsub and do something like `echo foo | awk '{k=sprintf("%8s", $0); gsub(" ", "0", k); print k}'
`

Comment: The `gsub` solution will replace spaces in the input as well: `echo "x y" | awk '{k=sprintf("%8s", $0); gsub(" ", "0", k); print k}'` will make `x y` `x0y` with some leading zeoes.

Comment: @Walter makes a good point.  That should be `k=sprintf("%8s", $1)`, or even better `'{$1=sprintf("%8s", $1); gsub(" ", "0", $1)}'`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to print the number n width total with w, you can use

```
n=12
w=8
printf "%0*d\n" $w $n
```

When you want the result in a var, you can use

```
printf -v j "%0*d" $w $n
echo "j=[$j]"
# Result:
j=[00000012]
```

It becomes more complex when you want to support strings as well.
A simple patch seems to work

```
s="Hello"
w=8
# Wrong:
printf "%*s\n" $w "$s" | tr ' ' '0'
```

The problem with this solution is that it will also replace the spaces in `$s`. You can use a `sed` construction for this:

```
s="Hello World with Spaces"
w=40
printf "%*s\n" $w "$s"| sed -r ':a;s/^( *) /\10/;ta'
j=$(printf "%*s" $w "$s"| sed -r ':a;s/^( *) /\10/;ta')
```

The `sed`construction will loop over the input, replacing one space each time (the last leading space) with a `0`. The `\1` will put back the other leading spaces.
When it is hard to understand, look how to replace 2 spaces by 'x':

```
printf "%*s\n" $w "$s"| sed -r 's/^( *) /\1x/;s/^( *) /\1x/'
```

EDIT: The solution is not perfect. When the inputstring starts with spaces, these spaces are replaced by zeroes too, and that might not be desired behaviour: `s=" I started with a space"`.

The solution seems to be calculating the number of zeroes first: The total width `$w` minus the stringlength `${#s}`. When you need at least one additional `0`, you can use

```
printf "%0*d%s\n" $(($w - ${#s})) 0 "$s"
```

Comment: If not number if alpha numeric, say n=ABC123 , need j output as  [00ABC123]

Comment: Replacing strings is more difficult, especially when you consider spaces in the string. See edit for an improved command.

Comment: i see using something like printf "%*s\n" $w "$s"| sed -r 's/^( *) /\1x/;s/^( *) /\1x/'  would give length 42 like (                 xxHello World with Spaces) rather than expected length 40 like (               xxHello World with Spaces). But another command printf "%*s\n" $w "$s"| sed -r ':a;s/^( *) /\10/;ta' is giving length 40. Where is the difference coming?

Comment: To put it into simple way printf "%*s\n" $w "$s"| sed -r ':a;s/^( *) /\10/;ta'  we are using "\10" and the back reference \1 contains spaces. Assuming there are 3 spaces before text "Hello World with Spaces" since we used "\10" the output  generally is (3spaces000Hello World with Spaces). Where the initial spaces are gone. Could pls explain

Comment: printf "%*s\n" $w "$s"| sed -r 's/^( *) /\1x/;s/^( *) /\1x/' | wc retuns 41 with me (including newline character, I hope your output is not ending with `\r\n`). I do not understand your different line lenghts.  
`\s\s\sHello` is changed into `000Hello` because there is a space after `)` in `s/^( *) /\10/`. The back ref matches 2 spaces, the third one is replaced by a `0`.